# Rounding small fraction like 2.234556440301284e-100 to 2.23e-100 in python

Tags: python, statistics, pearson-correlation, significant-digits

I'm trying to print a very small p-value to a plot `(p-value = 4.3289045262877305e-11)`. I need to round it to have fewer digits after the decimal so it will fit `(4.33e-11)` but when I'm using `round(,3)` it returns `0.0`. How can I return the number like this `4.33e-11`?

Comment: *I'm trying to print ...*. If you just want to print it in that format, use a format statement. Don't round the number itself. `print("%.3g" % p_value)`

Answer (score 1):

When you use round you are changing the value and in your example rounding to the nearest thousandth.  You only want to change the display format.
   "{:.2e}".format(4.3289045262877305e-11)
will create a string with the representation you want. 4.33e-11

More details: https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-print-a-number-in-scientific-notation-in-python

Answer (score -1):

When using `round(,3)` you are rounding up the actual value to `0,00`, not the displayed value.
If you actually need to round the value itself and not the displayed one, I would suggest you to multiply it by `e11`, then `round (,3)`, then devide it by `e11` to get the rounded number.